# Can Clonidine or chemically similar drugs (i.e. Guanfacine) cause or worsen Psoriasis?

Tags: side-effects, blood-pressure, psoriasis

Can [Clonidine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clonidine) or chemically similar drugs (i.e. [Guanfacine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guanfacine)) cause or worsen Psoriasis? If so, in what mechanism?

I didn't find any data about Guanfacine but I have found few articles mentioning Clonidnie:

- [This case study article from 1981](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamadermatology/article-abstract/541635)
- [This study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2921739/) (which I am not the authority to carefully analyze) listed it as one of the "Less commonly reported agents" (lesser than most commonly reported agents, and, lesser than "Other associated agents")
- [This study](https://journals.lww.com/ijru/Fulltext/2019/14001/Drug_Induced_Psoriasis.6.aspx)

Clonidine is an hypotensive agent and [various other hypotensive medications](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34611920/) have been suggested as worsening an existing Psoriasis.

Answer (score 2):

"Guanfacine and clonidine appear to have similar efficacy for the treatment of hypertension and a similar pattern of adverse effects." [1]

"About 15%–20% of patients develop contact dermatitis when using the transdermal system." [1]

"Clonidine is associated with Raynaud's phenomenon" [2],[3]

Dermatologic manifestation of clonidine - [3]

1. Pityriasis Rosea
2. Hyperpigmentation
   but association with psorisis is not mentioned in below texts.

Also from case study causal nature cannot be determined

Ref-
[1] Goodman & Gilman 13E Chapter 12 P 203
[2] HPIM 20E
[3] Fitzpatrick 9E